# How to count number of particular items in a list in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the following code to try and generate a list showing the count of each item in the `letters` list within an AngularJS controller:

```
$scope.letters = ['a','b','c'];
$scope.letterdata = ['a','b','a','c','b','a'];

$scope.counts = $scope.letters.map(function (x) {
    $scope.letterdata.filter(function (y) {
        return (x == y);
    }).length;
});
```

I would like to get `[3,2,1]` as the output, but this is showing as `[null,null,null]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing `return` statement inside `map()`.

```
$scope.counts = $scope.letters.map(function (x) {
    return $scope.letterdata.filter(function (y) {
    ^^^^^^
        return (x == y);
    }).length;
});
```

```js
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var letterdata = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a'];

var counts = letters.map(function (x) {
    return letterdata.filter(function (y) {
        return(x == y);
    }).length;
});
console.log(counts);
```

> but this is showing as `[null,null,null]`.

You should be getting `[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]` as nothing is returned, by default `undefined` is returned.

---

Equivalent code written using ES2015 [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
$scope.letters.map(x => $scope.letterdata.filter(y => x == y).length)
```

```js
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var letterdata = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a'];

var counts = letters.map(x => letterdata.filter(y => x == y).length);
console.log(counts);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var data = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a'];

_.reduce(list, function(counts, value) {
    counts.push(_.size(data) - _.size(_.without(data, value)));
    return counts;
}, []);
```